# javascript document.write using quotes within quotes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a line of HTML...

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="img/myLogos/myLogo1.png" alt=""  /></a></li>
```

I have this function to print it

```
function drawAccounts(){
document.write("<li><a href="#"><img src="img/myLogos/myLogo1.png" alt=""  /></a></li>");}
```

I can get the list item to draw but not the image or the alt tag

I've tried \" and &qout; but nothing changes

are there any other things I should try to pass these strings? would parsing between every quote help?

Comment: You should do this the better way and create the elements and add them to the DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use single quotes like this:

```
function drawAccounts(){
    document.write('<li><a href="#"><img src="img/myLogos/myLogo1.png" alt=""  /></a></li>');
}
```

Comment: you know what, I tried that before and for some reason it didn't work. now it did (stupid machines) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to print quotes within a string in JavaScript, you can always switch between single and double quotes:

```
var myString = "Hey it's sunny outside!";
```

And here's the version with the escaped quotes:

```
var str = "<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"img/myLogos/myLogo1.png\" alt=\"\"/></a></li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions, you can use single quotes -

```
document.write("<li><a href='#'><img src='img/myLogos/'"
  + "'myLogo1.png' alt=''  /></a></li>");
```

You can escape your quotes,

```
document.write("<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"img/myLogos/"
  + "myLogo1.png\" alt=\"\"  /></a></li>");
```

And you could also switch the order of the quotes,

```
document.write('<li><a href="#"><img src="img/myLogos/'
  + 'myLogo1.png" alt=""  /></a></li>');
```

And you can also escape the single quotes,

```
document.write('<li><a href=\'#\'><img src=\'img/myLogos/'
  + 'myLogo1.png\' alt=\'\'  /></a></li>');
```